# How do I solve a dirty index in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, github, pull

I have the following problem in eclipse:

[image]

How do I solve a dirty index?

Answer (score 18):

The index is the place in git where you register the changes you want to include in your next commit (via `git add`).

If you have no changes recorded on your index at all, the index is considered **clean**, but if there are files added to the index, the index is considered **dirty**.

The same applys to your working tree (the checked out files from your repository). If you made changes to them, they are **dirty** otherwise they are **clean**.

To make your index clean you could do a `reset` to just remove the changes from the index but not from the working tree, to also remove them from the working tree you can use `git stash` via the command line, or via the *Git Repositories* view in Eclipse.

[image: Eclipse Git Stash]

When you stash changes they get saved just like a commit but you easily regain and delete stashes. You can consider them as some kind of cache. You can read more [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing).

If you `stash` the changes you can regain them by applying them back to the repository via the command line (`git stash apply`) or via EGit (see Stashed Commits).

Answer (score 0):

Stash your changes then pull your branch

apply stashed changes once you pulled your branch